# Como juntar arrays com as chaves repetidas?

Tags: php, array

Tenho o seguinte **código**

```
$teste1 = array(
      1 => array( 1 => 'teste1', 2 => 'teste2', 3 => 'teste3'),
      2 => array(3 => 'teste4', 5 => 'teste5')
);

$teste2 = array(
      1 => array( 3 => 'teste6', 4 => 'teste7')
);

function uniqKeys($arr1, $arr2){

    if(empty($arr1)){
        return $arr2;
    }

    foreach ($arr1 as $key1 => $value1) {
        foreach ($arr2 as $key2 => $value2) {
            if ($key2 == $key1) {
                foreach($value2 as $key3 => $value3) {
                    array_push($arr1[$key1], $value3);
                }
            }
        }
     }

     return $arr1;       
}

print_r(uniqKeys($teste1, $teste2));
```

**resultado**

```
Array
(
[1] => Array
    (
        [1] => teste1
        [2] => teste2
        [3] => teste3
        [4] => teste6
        [5] => teste7
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [3] => teste4
        [5] => teste5
    )

)
```

Gostaria de saber se existe uma forma mais limpa para fazer essa junção, fiz um looping tradicional, mas como são muitos dados, irá exigir muito do servidor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se as chaves forem necessariamente numéricos, é possível fazer da seguinte forma:

```
function uniqKeys($arr1, $arr2)
{
    foreach($arr2 as $key => $value)
    {
        $arr1[$key] = array_key_exists($key, $arr1) ? array_merge($arr1[$key], $value) : $value;
    }

    return $arr1;
}
```

Isto é, percorre o segundo arranjo e, se já existir a chave no primeiro arranjo, mescla os dois valores, caso contrário define o valor como sendo o valor do segundo. Veja como ficaria:

```
$teste1 = array(
      1 => array( 1 => 'teste1', 2 => 'teste2', 3 => 'teste3'),
      2 => array(3 => 'teste4', 5 => 'teste5')
);

$teste2 = array(
      1 => array( 3 => 'teste6', 4 => 'teste7')
);

function uniqKeys($arr1, $arr2)
{
    foreach($arr2 as $key => $value)
    {
        $arr1[$key] = array_key_exists($key, $arr1) ? array_merge($arr1[$key], $value) : $value;
    }

    return $arr1;
}

print_r(uniqKeys($teste1, $teste2));
```

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/ZL4VF3).

Porém, se as chaves puderem ser *string*, é possível utilizar diretamente a função nativa `array_merge_recursive`:

```
$teste1 = array(
      "a" => array( 1 => 'teste1', 2 => 'teste2', 3 => 'teste3'),
      "b" => array(3 => 'teste4', 5 => 'teste5')
);

$teste2 = array(
      "a" => array( 3 => 'teste6', 4 => 'teste7')
);

print_r(array_merge_recursive($teste1, $teste2));
```

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/htbGRi).

Vale lembrar que não adianta definir as chaves como `"1"` e `"2"`, pois mesmo sendo essencialmente uma *string* o interpretador do PHP irá tratar o valor como inteiro e a união dos arranjos não será a esperada.

Comment: Exatamente isso, Obrigado!